# C++ calling Java object method: Access Violation

Tags: java, jvm, java-native-interface

I'm trying to implement a Java/C++ binding for a sound streaming class. To keep my example simple, I will reduce it to its seeking method, which is enough to describe my problem:

```
public abstract class JSoundStream extends SoundStream {
    public abstract void seek(float timeOffset);
}
```

For testing, I use the following implementation:

```
@Override public void seek(float timeOffset) {
    System.out.println("seek(" + timeOffset + ")");
}
```

The `seek` method is a callback method, delegated to by a native C++ functions that serves as a callback for whatever plays the stream. Picture a media player application with a fast forward function as an example:

"Fast forward" button pressed -> Streaming library invokes C++ callback `seek` -> Delegate to Java method `seek`

*Note this is just an example, neither the Event Dispatch Thread nor anything else funky is involved.*

When an instance of `JSoundStream` gets created, a native method is called that will save back both the Java VM pointer (`JavaVM*`) as well as the Java object reference (`jobject`). I do this because I cannot control when exactly the callback is called, and I know of no way to get the JNI environment or the object *live* with no Java references whatsoever. So I save back that information at the time of object creation, where I do have the references.

Inside of the C++ `seek` method, I'm trying to invoke the Java `seek` method this way:

```
virtual void OnSeek(float timeOffset) {
    JNIEnv* env;
    jvm->AttachCurrentThread((void**)&env, NULL);
    env->CallVoidMethod(binding, m_seek, (jfloat)timeOffset);
}
```

Where `binding` is the `jobject`, `jvm` the Java VM pointer and `m_seek` the `jmethodID` of the `seek` method I obtained before.

However, that invocation of `CallVoidMethod` will result in an access violation in `jvm.dll`. All of the pointers and values are valid for what I can say, and I did make sure the Java object does not get garbage collected. I believe that storing the `jobject` and / or the Java VM pointer is the source of the problem, but then again I cannot see why, because those values are not changing while the program is running.

Can anybody see a problem in the way I am approaching this? How else - without storing references - would I invoke a Java object method from C++ code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach should be correct, if

1. Your jobject has been retrieved with `binding = env->NewGlobalRef(binding_passed_as_argument);`
2. You do not call `AttachCurrentThread` from the same thread multiple times - use TLS to store the `JNIEnv` pointer.

Comment: 2. is given, in fact I just added it to the above example to avoid people telling me I forgot it. :)

But about 1., I will try that. In the native creation method the `jobject` got passed as an argument and I stored that rather than creating a global ref like you described.

Comment: @pdinklag: Then you're keeping a long expired local reference, that most definitely won't work. Treat whatever's passed to you from java as you would local variables.